# Complex Numbers : Proof

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that if $w,z$ are complex numbers such that $|w|=|z|=1$ and $wz\ne -1$, then $\frac{w+z}{1+wz}$ is a real number.

Do I substitute $w$ and $z$ for $a+bi$ and $c+di?$ How do I do this?

Comment: What's the condition for a complex number to be a real number ?

Comment: A number is real if and only if it is equal to its own conjugate.

Comment: @Oran2013, good. Check my Hint. It's a good exercise if you work that on your own without looking at the answers posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down into components $w = a+bi$ and $z=c+di$ is going to be extremely tedious.  Like Fib1123 says, you want to show that $\frac{w+z}{1+wz}$ is its own conjugate.  In general,
$$
    \overline{\frac{w+z}{1 + wz}} = \frac{\bar w+ \bar z}{1 + \bar w \bar z}
$$
Now multiply by $1=\frac{wz}{wz}$ and use the fact that 
$$
|w| = w \bar w = |z| = z \bar z = 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Since $|w|=|z|=1,$ you can write $w=e^{i\theta}$ and $z=e^{i \alpha}$ for $\theta, \alpha \in [0,2 \pi].$ Now show that 
$$\overline{ \left( \frac{w+z}{1+wz} \right)}=\frac{w+z}{1+wz} .$$

Answer (score 2):

Remmember that $w\cdot\overline{w}=|w|^2=1$ and $z\cdot\overline{z}=|z|^2=1$

$$\frac{w+z}{1+wz}=\frac{(w+z)(1+\overline{w}\cdot\overline{z})}{(1+wz)(1+\overline{w}\cdot\overline{z})}=\frac{w+z+w\cdot \overline{w}\cdot\overline{z}+\overline{z}\cdot z\cdot\overline{w}}{|1+wz|^2}=$$

$$=\frac{w+z+\overline{w}+\overline{z}}{|1+wz|^2}=\frac{2\cdot Re(w+z)}{|1+wz|^2} \in \Bbb R$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $w=e^{ia}$ and $z=e^{ib}$ with

$a+b\neq (2k+1)\pi$.

then

$$\frac{w+z}{1+wz}=\frac{e^{ia}+e^{ib}}{1+e^{i(a+b)}}$$

$=\frac{1}{2(1+\cos(a+b))}(e^{ia}+e^{ib})(1+e^{-i(a+b})$

$=\frac{1}{2(1+\cos(a+b))}(e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{-ia}+e^{-ib})$

$$=\frac{\cos(a)+\cos(b) }{1+\cos(a+b)}\in \Bbb R$$

Comment: I don't agree with denominator $2$: it is $2+2\cos(a+b)$. Nevertheless it is a real and the line of reasoning is not ruined.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oui . Merci. j'ai corrigé.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $w=\cos2A+i\sin2A,z=\cos2B+i\sin2B$

Using $\cos2u=2\cos^2u-1,\sin2v=2\sin v\cos v$ and [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

$w+z=\cos2A+\cos2B+i(\sin2A+\sin2B)$ $=2\cos(A-B)\left(\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)\right)$

$1+wz=1+\cos2(A+B)+i\sin2(A+B)$ $=2\cos(A+B)\left(\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)\right)$

Comment: You like Prosthaphaeresis Formulas, isn't it ? :) I like them too for the poetic sonority of "Prosthaphaeresis" (I imagine being on the Acropolis, with the nice sonority of Greek language... :).

Answer (score 0):

setting $$w=a+bi$$ and $$z=c+di$$ we obtain
$$\frac{a+c+i(b+d)}{1+(a+bi)(c+di)}=$$
$$\frac{a+c+i(b+d)}{1+ac-bd+i(bc+ad)}=$$
$$\frac{(a+c+i(b+d))(1+ac-bd-i(bc+ad))}{(1+ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2}=$$
$$\frac{2(a+c)}{(1+ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2}$$
and this is a real number

Comment: 0% content of insight. And yet complex numbers are so fun to play with... :-)